# Iphone Push Notification: Certificate revoked

Tags: iphone, push-notification, certificate-revocation

I've an Iphone application made with Titanium, I've enabled notifications. In order to send the notifications (sandbox) I'm using 
https://github.com/simonwhitaker/PyAPNs, everything was working great. But suddenly  when I try to send a notification, I receive this message:

error:14094414:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate revoked

In the provisioning portal, the certificate is enabled. I don't know what's the 
problem.

would It be possible that problem comes from I've installed the app again in the iphone?

I'm not sure if I should revoke the "Development Push SSL Certificate" in the provisioning portal and start from scratch.

Comment: Apple made some changes to the certificates in December that required developers to update their certs. Did it stop working only today, or last month?

Comment: today, I've revoked my certificate and done a new one and now it's working again. But i don't what happend